# Some different words for "may be"

Tags: meaning

I caught myself writing "may be" too much instead of something else. What else can I write alternatively?

Comment: It might be better if you could provide us with some of your sentences.

Comment: also, note that "may be" and "maybe" are different, although of the same origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, I will write alternatively such as *probably be*, *perhaps*, *might be*, *could be*, or *would be*. Perhaps you would like to look up some physical or online dictionaries. Good luck!

Comment: It was the word "perhaps" which I couldn't remember. Thanks